# PHP Many to Many Set Ids

Tags: php, mysql, many-to-many

For the purpose of this question, lets assume we have a many to many relationship set up using three tables:

```
courses - with a id and name
students - with id and name
enrollment - with course_id and student_id
```

In rails, if you do a has_and_belongs_to_many, you can do

```
course.student_ids = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

And rails says that it will add / delete ids as necessary. I would like to do something similar in PHP. Something like

```
set_courses($student_id, array(1,2,3,4,5));
```

What I was wondering is if there is a good way to implement this efficiently in PHP. I can think of a way to do it in 3 queries (one to get current ids, one to delete unnecessary ones, and one to add new ones). Is there a way to do this in one or even two queries?

Thanks!

Comment: You have told us you have three tables and their field structure. What are you trying to do exactly?

Comment: Rails **is not** a programming language.

Comment: Sorry, I will edit the post to make it clearer.

Comment: @zerkms I apologize, I should have made what I want clearer. I am looking for an efficient way to implement a similar method (not for a method that already exists), using less than 3 mysql queries.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm understanding you correctly than you can do it in 2:

1. delete all current enrollments
2. insert enrollments

I'd use transactions, though, to make sure both are executed.

Comment: Sounds perfect. Love the simplicity. Thanks for the help!